# What if c = 0 in segmented least squares in OPT(j)= min1≤i≤j{e(i,j)+c+OPT(i−1)}

Tags: algorithm

we are trying to find out what if c=0. in OPT(j)= min1≤i≤j{e(i,j)+c+OPT(i−1)}
ei,j represents minimum error of any line

Comment: Your question will need to be more detailed - what are you trying to do and why?

Comment: Please add *context*... RIght now you just have given a random formula. It really depends on what problem you aim to solve, what `OPT` is, etc.

Comment: the sement pi, …., pj is used in an optimum solution for the subproblem if and only if the minimum is obtained using index i. 
Specifically, ei,j denotes the minimum error of any line with respect to pi, …., pj. C is an additive for each segment, where C>0. In other words, C is somehow the penlaty to add one segment. The running time of this algorithm is O(n3).